# Cómo incluir librerías de PostgreSQL en Java utilizando Maven?

Tags: java, base-de-datos, postgresql, xml, maven

Estoy utilizando Maven en el entorno de NetBeans, y por más de que adiciono PostgreSQL, o cualquier librería para manipular una base de datos, no me lee las importaciones.
Este es mi código pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.proyecto</groupId>
    <artifactId>zzzeliminar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.29</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.proyecto.zzzeliminar.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for manual attach debugging -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run@debug -->
                        <id>debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=localhost:8000</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE debugging -->
                        <id>ide-debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE profiling -->
                        <id>ide-profile</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg1}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg2}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg3}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg4}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg5}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Estoy utilizando Maven de esta manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aquí están mis dependencias (también añadí JavaFX, el cual viene por defecto, pero eso pienso que no debería de tener ninguna clase de incompatibilidad):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando lo importo, me dice que no existe:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Qué tendría que hacer para que me permita utilizar las librerías de SQL? Ya sea de PostgreSQL o MySQL, o cualquier otro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tiene que especificar la dependencia en `module-info.java` .Para eso debe añadir  `requires  mysql.connector.java;`  en `module-info.java` .
en su caso sería así :

```
module com.com.proyecto.zzzeliminar.app {
    
    requires javafx.controls;
    ///////////////////////////////////////////

    requires  mysql.connector.java;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////
    exports com.com.proyecto.zzzeliminar.app;
}
```

lo que tiene que añadir esta entre líneas de comentario

Comment: Cómo sería para el caso de Postgresql?

Comment: Hice lo que detallaste, y compila correctamente. No obstante, aún no puedo importar las librerías sql, como por ejemplo `import java.sql.*`;
Cómo sería posible importar dichas librerías?, por otro lado en `module-info.java` la primera línea me aparece como `module com.com.proyecto.zzzeliminar` sin la "app", tendría que añadirlo o agregar otro module?

Comment: Hice lo que especificaste para el caso de Postgresql, añadiendo `requires org.postgresql.jdbc`, después lo importé en App como `import org.porgresql.PGConnection`, significa que para estableces la conexión con la base de Datos, se tendría que utilizar la clase PGConnection? (Disculpa mi ignorancia, lo mucho que he utilizado para conectarme a una base de datos, es a la antigua con Connection).

Comment: por ejemplo para importar ServerController es   `import com.mysql.cj.admin.ServerController;`  no  java.sql.....

Comment: Oh, perfecto, me quedó todo claro, muchísimas gracias :)